# Extjs combobox to display records with value fetched from data store rest/jsp request

Tags: javascript, extjs

With ExtJs (4.2) version, wanted to know how to filter the empty records from the combobox dropdown list.

The code uses Extjs store to fetch a data from jsp, the result is a json object. Say below is the results rendered,

```
{ "data" : [
     {"source":"system1","key1" : "value system1", "key2" : " value for system1"},
     {"source":"system2","key1" : "value 11", "key2" : " value for key1, value 12"},
     {"source":"system3" },   //Blank or empty key1, key2 record.
    ....
}
```

### Js code with ExtJs

```
I am using ExtJs to display a combobox (Dropdown) below is the code fragment

      var dataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['key1', 'key2'],
            proxy:
            {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '<url to a jsp file which retruns json data>',
                reader:
                {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'templates'
                }
            }
        });
        
...

    var screenPanel = {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Panel - Data',
                margin: '0 10 15 15',
                padding: 10,
                flex: 1,
                width:"100%",
                layout: 'anchor',
                defaults: {
                    labelWidth: 160,
                },
                items: [
                {
                        xtype: 'checkbox',
                        name: 'visibility',
                        id: 'visibility',
                        fieldLabel : 'Check to enable', 
                        value:false                                 
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        anchor: '80%',
                        name: 'combodropdown',
                        itemId: 'combo1',
                        fieldLabel: 'Dropdown selection',
                        displayField: 'key2',
                        valueField: 'key1',
                        store: dataStore,
                    },{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        anchor: '80%',
....
```

The combox dropdown is listing the empty record as well. Is there a way to filter that value. In the above case the "source" : "system3" doesn't have key1 and key2 value but the xtype:combo (name: combodropdown) is listing a blank item as well.

Is there any example, on using an event to filter the data that are empty. like onClick event to filter the data like below

```
....
                      {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        anchor: '80%',
                        name: 'combodropdown',
                        itemId: 'combo1',
                        fieldLabel: 'Dropdown selection',
                        displayField: 'key2',
                        valueField: 'key1',
                        store: dataStore,
                        
                        //some thing like this
                        onClick: function(value1,value2){
                            alert('clicked combox dropdown')
                            //data store value empty return something
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use store [filter](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-filters). Something like:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var dataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['key1', 'key2'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'comboData.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                }
            },
            filters: [
                function (item) {
                    return !Ext.isEmpty(item.get('key1')) && !Ext.isEmpty(item.get('key2'));
                }
            ]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: "Sample Panel",
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                name: 'combodropdown',
                itemId: 'combo1',
                fieldLabel: 'Dropdown selection',
                displayField: 'key2',
                valueField: 'key1',
                store: dataStore,
                listeners: {
                    expand: function(comboBox) {
                        console.log(comboBox.getStore().getRange());
                    }
                }
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```